# CFG_EXTRAS equivalent for ros2/colcon

Tags: ros, catkin-package, colcon, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a ROS1 `CMakeLists.txt` that contains:

```
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include/
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
  CFG_EXTRAS Findthis_package.cmake)
```

For `colcon` on `Foxy`, how do we specify loading in an extra `.cmake` file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383380/cfg_extras-equivalent-for-ros2/colcon/) by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2021-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did a little more searching, and in `colcon` the keyword is `CONFIG_EXTRAS` and is used in `ament_package()`, as [documented here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#basic-project-outline).

So, my solution is to use this instead:

```
ament_package(
  CONFIG_EXTRAS cmake/Findthis_package.cmake)
```

Note that the full relative path is needed, whereas `catkin_package()` assumed the `cmake` directory.

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2021-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0